# Why was the Buddy Complex "second season" just a two part finale?

Tags: buddy-complex

It seems like there were expectations for a full second season of Buddy Complex, e.g. [from here](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2014-03-30/buddy-complex-anime-to-be-continued) in March 2014:

> ... the official Twitter account and website for the anime [confirmed](https://twitter.com/buddycomplex/status/450292920180932608) that the series will still [continue](http://news.buddy-complex.jp/app-def/S-102/news/?p=532).

But then, only three months later, [a two-episode finale was announced instead](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2014-06-01/new-2-part-buddy-complex-sequel-anime-to-air-this-fall/.75100), seemingly to the [surprise](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/bbs/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=2850981) (a reaction of confusion common in other forums as well, which I share) of many. The finale was released in September 2014. The finale announcement article also concludes with the same note that "the story will still continue" but this seems to be more copy-pasted from the first announcement than an actual announcement (it links back to the same old Twitter post).

Why did Buddy Complex not get a full second season? Was a second season scheduled and then reduced to two episodes because of poor sales or anything like that? Is another season still planned? I don't know Japanese and so searching for sources was difficult. I'm looking primarily for official news and announcements, interviews, etc.

Comment: I didn't keep up with the goings-on surrounding Buddy Complex, but studios have this nasty habit of announcing "a new production is in the works!", and people getting excited for a sequel, only for that so-called "new production" to turn out to be a one-off OVA, or a manga spinoff, or - worst of all - a pachinko machine. Same deal here - nothing in the language of either of the links in your blockquote implies a full-cour second season; this seems to just be an interpolation by hopeful fans of the series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official [tweet](https://twitter.com/buddycomplex/status/450292920180932608) you link to simply says: "Regarding *Buddy Complex* TOKYO MX, that everyone [kindly] watched episode 13, thank you very much! That is to say... To be continued！This work will continue! Please wait for the follow-up. Later on, [we'll] release BD privileged information! #buddycom" (「【バディ・コンプレックス】TOKYO MXにて第13話をご覧頂きました皆様、ありがとうございました！という事で・・・To be continued！本作品はまだ続きます！続報をお待ち下さいませ。この後BD特典情報を公開します！ #buddycom」)

There is **no mention or implication** within the text that indicates any particular set **length of running time**, nor even the **media type** of the promised follow-up. 「作品」 (*sakuhin*) is a non-specific word for a work of some sort, such as a production, a piece of art, a piece of work, handiwork, even someone's opus.

Thus, the 2014/10/27 post on the official [website](http://www.buddy-complex.jp/news.php) announcing the [完結編](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%90%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%83%BB%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%97%E3%83%AC%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B9#Blu-ray) (*kanketsuhen*, the last program of a series), which was released November 21st, 2014 and comprised of a two-parter 前編 (*zenpen*, first part) and 後編 (*kouhen*, second [after] part), does not in any way conflict with the original Twitter announcement. This means that, no, **a second season of TV anime was not scheduled and then cancelled**. 「完結編」 (*kanketsuhen*), by its very meaning, is the last program of a series; to title a release that way is to **explicitly state that there are no plans for ever produce a following work** such as a second TV anime season.

Therefore, it does not seem that proficient readers of Japanese would have misunderstood the tweet to promise a season's worth of upcoming anime. Someone who reported on the tweet in English for an English-language source seems to have jumped to a conclusion regarding in what sense the 「作品」 (*sakuhin*) would continue.